# How to remove nested RequireJS calls?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, amd, nested

I got a job to refac a quite complex app by introducing RequireJS.
The app uses a engine with a complex class tree.
While struggling to achieve my goals and learning about AMD I got a lot of questions but I'll try to stick just to the first one.
I got a bad time loading just jQuery+knockout+mapping+Sammy but managed to work it using nested requireJS calls.
The code belows works but I'm not satisfied with the nested requires.
How to remove the nesting and just use a single requireJS call?

```
    // my first require: myBoot.js
```

/*
[www](index.html)
  |------scripts (app lies here)
            |-------libs (3th party libs)
            |-------engine (base URL)

*/

requirejs.config({
"baseUrl": "scripts/engine",
"paths": {
    "app": "../",
    "lib": "../libs",
    "knockout": "../libs/knockout-2.2.1.debug"
}//,
//"shim": {
//    "lib/jquery.mylibA": ["lib/jquery-2.0.0"],
//    "lib/jquery.mylibB": ["lib/jquery-2.0.0"]
//}
});

// load jquery
requirejs(["lib/jquery-2.0.0"], function ($) {

// load third party libraries
requirejs(["knockout", "lib/knockout.mapping-latest", "lib/sammy-latest.min"], function       (ko, komap, Sammy) {

    // Oh god! why?
    ko.mapping = komap;
    window.ko = ko;
    window.Sammy = Sammy;

    // load my self-made libs
    requirejs(["lib/jquery.mylibA", "lib/jquery.mylibB"

    // load my engine e FOOlings
    , "FOOEngine"
    // each FOOlings is a node in a FOO tree of classes, the goal here is to load them   by demand
    , "FOOling00"
    , /* 40 more FOOlings */
    , "FOOling41"

    // load my app
    ,"app/xmlLoader", "app/MoreLoaderStuff", "app/App"]);
});
});

/*
// example on FOOlings:

function FOOling21(settings) {
var self = this;

// lots of stuff: initialize, constructor, propertiers, methods...

//#region Constructor

if (settings) {
    $.extend(this, settings);
}

//#endregion

// can depend on other FOOlings like FOOling11 and FOOling02
// can request data from web services
// can uses ko to do binding data
// can depend on other libs
// etc

return this;
}

// can turn in? (for the sake of the example, F21 extendes F02 and uses F11 for generic stuff)

define(["FOOling11", "FOOling02"], function(f11, f02) {
return {
    function FOOling21() {
    var self = this;


    //#region Constructor

    if (f02) {
        $.extend(this, f02);
    }

    //#endregion

    //...

    return this;
    }
}

// or is a best pratice to do this way?
define(["FOOling11", "FOOling02"], function(f11, f02) {
return {
    var settings = f02;
    function FOOling21(settings) {

    // no changes ...

    return this;
    }
}

*/
</pre></code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[I posted an answer here that may help answer your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197696/knockout-js-mapping-plugin-with-require-js)**

The answer I linked to above will explain this process a little more, but you can rely heavily on the require.js configuration object to build up scripts as shown here:

```
var require = {
  paths: {
    'knockout': '...',
    'mapping': '...'
  },

  // configuration dependencies

  deps: ['knockout', 'mapping'],

  // configuration callback

  callback: function (ko, mapping) {
    ko.mapping = mapping;
  }
};
```

In the sample above, `deps` are loaded with require and `callback` is then fired where we are able to attach `mapping` to the `ko` object. All future requirements for knockout will include the `mapping` property we just added:

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
  ko.mapping // mapping is accessible in other modules
});
```

Using this pattern, you can setup and "compose" scripts as needed as part of the overall require.js configuration/initialization process.

Comment: Nate is right and Mallim shared a nice example. Sellmeadog marked as answer why this solved my problem and give me a precious insight about the AMD.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using nesting because you're trying to load dependencies for non-AMD code - the way you're supposed to do this is via [`shim`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) in your `requirejs.config` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this as a guideline to help you with the organization:
https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim