# Knockout Mapping plugin in Durandal giving undefined

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

I'm having a problem I've trying to solve for 2 days and now I just give up, so this is my last resource, I'm trying to load a JSON response into an observableArray (KO) in Durandal but everytime I call the function ko.mapping.fromJSON is comes with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJSON' of undefined
```

I understand I need to download the plugin and load it on the main.js

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    'text': '../lib/require/text',
    'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
    'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
    'transitions' : '../lib/durandal/js/transitions',
    'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout',
    'mapping': '../lib/knockout/knockout.mapping',
    'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
    'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1'
},
urlArgs: 'v=1.0.0.1',
shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jQuery'
   }
}
});
```

Knockout is working fine, I'm able to update fields and everything, but when I try to use the ko.mapping I'm having problems:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'plugins/router', 'knockout', 'mapping'], function (app, router, ko) {

var clients = ko.observableArray([]);

return {
    displayName: 'My Page',
    clients: clients,
    activate: function () {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "backend/ServerServices.php",
            data: {
                s: 'listadodeclientes'
            }
        }).then(function( msg ) {
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(msg, clients);

        });

    },
    showMessage: function () {
        router.navigate('crearcliente');
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Which version of Durandal are you using?

Answer (score 3):

In order to use ko.mapping plugin with require.js you have to manualy set ko.mapping variable to ko.mapping library or use injected variable instead.

Sample:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'plugins/router', 'knockout', 'mapping'], function (app, router, ko, mapping) {
   ko.mapping = mapping;
   ko.mapping.fromJSON(...

   //or use injected mapping parameter
   mapping.fromJson(...


}
```

Look at the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805989/loading-knockout-mapping-plugin-using-require-js) question.