# knockout.mapping & Require.js bug

Tags: requirejs, knockout-mapping-plugin

So I am trying to integrate knockout.mapping.js with require.js. I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805989/loading-knockout-mapping-plugin-using-require-js) example.

Unfortunately, I keep on getting this error:

> GET http://[url]/Scripts/app/contractor/ko.js 404 (Not Found)
>   Uncaught Error: Script error for: ko

I have set up following files:

### app.index.js

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "../Scripts/app/contractor",
    "paths": {
        "app.index": "app.index",
        "knockout": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min",
        "mapping": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping",
        "knockout.bindings": "../../lib/knockout.bindings",
        "fu": "../../lib/jquery.fineuploader-3.8.0",
        "s2": "../../lib/select2",
        "jquery": "//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min",
        "jqueryui": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min",
        "moment": "../../lib/moment.min",
        "toastr": "../../lib/toastr"
    },
    "shim": {
        'mapping': {
            deps: ['knockout'],
            exports: 'mapping'
        }
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
require(['knockout', 'mapping', "main.index"], function (ko, mapping, bs) {
    ko.mapping = mapping;
    alert('ko: ' + ko + ', mapping: ' + ko.mapping);
    bs.run();
});
```

### main.index.js

```
    define(['knockout',
            'mapping',
            'indexViewModel'],
       function (ko, mapping, indexViewModel) {
           var
               run = function () {

                   var vm = new indexViewModel();


                   ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('#contractor-home-view'));
               };
           return {
               run: run
           };
       });
```

main.index.js is irrelevant at this point because the mapping is not loading properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `"ko.js"` file anywhere in your example. I can only assume that you have some other code that is trying to use a dependency called `"ko"` (rather than `"knockout"`) that does not exist.

Comment: I am loading knockout.js in the requirejs.config section. Funny thing is that when I make the config like this: "ko": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min". It tells me that knockout.js is missing.

Comment: sorry meant to say "it tells me that 'knockout' is missing"

Comment: http://www.autogenerated.com/2012/09/knockout-requirejs-amd-module-name.html

Answer (score 0):

Try making this in your `.config`

```
"shim": {
        'knockout': {
          exports: 'ko'
        },
        'mapping': {
          deps: ['knockout'],
          exports: 'mapping'
        }
    }
```