# Knockout Mapping with requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, knockout-mapping-plugin

I would like to use RequireJS to manage plugins in my site. I use knockout with the mapping plugin and I was reading the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449509/1070291 and I'm having a bit of trouble getting it going.

The callback seems to run after the actual require() statement, which means `ko.mapping` isn't defined

Any idea what I'm missing?

```
<script>
    var require = {
        paths: {
            "knockout": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min",
            "mapping": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping"
        },
        deps: ['knockout', 'mapping'],
        callback: function (ko, mapping) {
            ko.mapping = mapping;
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.8/require.min.js"></script>
<script>
    require(['knockout'], function (ko) {
        alert( 'ko: ' + ko + ', mapping: ' + ko.mapping);
    });
</script>
```

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WLegU/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost close to get it working. The only missing part is that you need to require even the `mapping` module, which in turn calls the callback first because it is a dependency.

```
require(['knockout', 'mapping'], function (ko) {
    console.log( 'ko: ' + ko + ', mapping: ' + ko.mapping );
});
```

[**Check Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WLegU/3/)

From the docs

> This callback function will be called when all the dependencies
>                   listed above in deps are loaded.

Because you were not requiring the `mapping` module, the callback was invoked later when the mapping module was loaded.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to sort it out.